# Slow repetitive execution of DDL and DML statements using JDBC

Tags: sql, performance, jdbc, ddl, dml

For integration tests running against 11 different RBDMS for a database abstraction library, I need to frequently reset the schema and/or data. This means, I run plenty of statements for most test-cases.

Schema resets are only needed at the beginning of a test-suite. For example:

```sql
DROP VIEW
DROP TABLE
DROP SEQUENCE
DROP PROCEDURE
...

CREATE TABLE
...
```

Data-resets are only needed for tests that write data. For example:

```sql
DROP SEQUENCE
DELETE FROM TABLE ...

CREATE SEQUENCE
INSERT INTO TABLE ...
```

Read-only tests are quite fast, as they don't need any resetting. Inutitively, I'd just read a SQL file into memory and execute every statement using this:

```java
// No bind variables, all hard parses
// Bind variables won't help much, though as the "hard-parse-reduction" isn't very big.
stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
```

On some systems, this is quite slow. Is there any better way to do this with JDBC? Or do I have to accept the fact that this can be slow...?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to reset/recreate the schema at the beginning of the test suite? I'd like to know why are you doing so, since I'm ensuring that the schema is place under version control, and  each test suite starts only after applying any unapplied changes from SCM. Each individual test begins with clearing the contents of all tables followed by inserting of test data. I can post details of this approach, if that is what you're looking for, otherwise I would be eating crow.

Comment: @Vineet: I just like to stay on the safe side, to be sure the schema is empty at the beginning, to prevent side-effects that may occur because of me playing around with schema objects while developing... :) I think other than that, we're doing pretty much the same...?

Comment: ah ok, I get your problem. In that event why don't you have a separate development and test schemas in your development database? I use DbDeploy for ensuring the test schema on the integration test server is always based off version control. Test schemas on developer machines that are used in unit tests are based on the developer's copy of DbDeploy scripts; dev schemas can be blown away and recreated from the versioned scripts if necessary. You could also use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/tutorial-using-oracle) instead of DbDeploy.

Comment: Thanks for those hints. I'll consider those tools when I create more automation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial idea: for faster deletes, many DBMS have a "truncate table" statement.

Another partial idea: instead of deleting and reinstalling everything at the start of the test, you could just copy the files of an empty database. This will require in-depth knowledge of all 11 DBMS though, and you'll need to shutdown the processes.

Comment: Truncate sometimes is slower than delete especially for small tables. Truncate resets quite a few other elements (indexes, sequences, auto_increment columns, etc). Besides, you cannot truncate a table referenced by other tables... I've tried using that but it peformed a lot worse :-/

Comment: File copying won't do the trick, I had thought of that before :). But as you said... I'm not going to learn how that works for all 11 RDBMS. Besides, the restart of Oracle/DB2 is not so fast :-/